# Confusion about units in fabric.js

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I'd like to figure out what are the units of `lineHeight` and `charSpacing` properties in fabric.js and how they are calculated.

In the documentation I couldn't find my answer or maybe I don't understand how it works exactly.

`lineHeight :` http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html#lineHeight
`charSpacing:` http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html#charSpacing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fabric's **lineHeight** corresponds to CSS `line-height`'s unitless value, which means it's a multiplier of the text's font size. The actual formula fabric.js uses to calculate line's height (in `text.getHeightOfLine()` method) is

```
maxHeight * this.lineHeight * this._fontSizeMult
```

where:

`maxHeight` is the font size of the largest character in the given line;

`_fontSizeMult` is a constant text line proportion to font size (in pixels) that equals `1.13` by default. Fabric.js uses `_fontSizeMult` multiplier to leave a little bit of extra room for underline and overline. So you might need to divide `text.lineHeight` by `fabric.Text.prototype._fontSizeMult` for this value to be consistent between fabric.js and CSS.

---

Fabric's **charSpacing** corresponds to CSS `letter-spacing`'s `em` units divided by 1000. I.e. a `fabric.Text` with `charSpacing = 500` will look more or less the same as a text with `letter-spacing: .5em;`.

---

Here's a comparison of fabric.js text (black) and HTML text (red):

```js
const canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('c')

canvas.add(new fabric.Text('text\ntext', {
  fontSize: 20,
  left: 0,
  top: 8,
  lineHeight: 2 / fabric.Text.prototype._fontSizeMult
}))

canvas.add(new fabric.Text('text', {
  fontSize: 20,
  left: 0,
  top: 80,
  charSpacing: 500
}))
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.text {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
}

.text1 {
  line-height: 2;
}

.text2 {
  letter-spacing: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.6.0/fabric.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <canvas id="c" width="80" height="100"></canvas>
    <span class="text text2">text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col text text1">
    <span>text</span>
    <span>text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You really helped me.